# Can i use espresso to test jetpack compose UI

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-espresso, android-testing

I have an existing test automation framwork that i want to reuse for a testing of new android application built in jetpack compose

I found a way to put resource ids in compose ui element but espresso is not picking them.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.